# Activator.CreateInstance(string assemblyName,string typName) in silverlight windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, activator, createinstance

I want to use Activator.CreateInstance(string assemblyName,string typName) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in my Windows Phone 7 app. But it doesn't seems to work.

Any ideas of solutions or work arounds?

Comment: Is the assembly part of your XAP package? What error are you getting? Some additional detail will help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've referenced the .net 4.0 (full framework) in your question. I think you want the Silverlight version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=VS.95).aspx

There isn't a version which matches the signature you're trying to use in Silverlight. You need to pass a Type and, optionally, any parameters the constructor of that type takes.

On the phone you can't load an assembly this way, only a type.

Comment: It's not nessesery to load an assembly, but I want to create an instanse from a class name.